# Convert Jquery code to javascript for .bind event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to convert `.bind` of jQuery to JavaScript. Here is the code:

```
$("#cke_bdy").bind("keypress", function(e) {

some code...
});
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#cke_bdy").addEventListener("keypress",function(e){  /* some code */ });` - seriously, this is all on mdn.

Comment: then how to unbind that keypress event..?

Comment: Your question is not showing the effort. This is a very trivial thing and you can find a lot information using search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM) of javascript :

Add an event listener on any element should be coded as :

```
element.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
```

Remove an event listener on any element should be coded as :

```
element.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
```

Example :

```
// For instance
var onClickOnId = function () {
    console.log('click on #id');
}

document.getElementById('#id').addEventListener('click', onClickOnId, true);

document.getElementById('#id').removeEventListener('click', onClickOnId, true);
```

But a question persist : Why would you not use jQuery to bind your events ?

By the way, .bind() is deprecated and should be replaced by .on() in the latest releases.

Comment: thank you so much,for your replay it's working fine..Thanx once again..